# Text in the <li> tag comes below the icon when it moves to next line

Tags: html, css, html-lists, font-awesome

I have created an un-ordered list with a set of li tags. I am using font awesome icon as the icon before the text in the starts.

```css
#facts i {
        margin-right: 1%;
        font-size: 150%;
        display: block;
        float: left;
    }
```

```html
<ul id="facts" class="fa-ul">
      <li class="text-muted">
        <h6 class="text-uppercase"><i class="fa fa-archive fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Inventory Menu 
        </h6>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h6 class="text-uppercase"><i class="fa fa-industry fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;<a href="warehouse_loc_maint_menu.html">Warehouse Location Maint Menu </a>
        </h6>
      </li>
```

The problem is that the text that comes in the next line comes below the fa icon. I want the text in the next line to start from the starting of the first line.

This is what comes as result:
[image: Text appears like this]

Comment: Atleast show us a working example so someone can help really fast.

Comment: what other examples do you want?

Comment: I think you got the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could help you

```css
#facts {
  width: 25px;
}
#facts i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
}
#facts li {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<ul id="facts" class="fa-ul">
  <li class="text-muted">
    <h6 class="text-uppercase"><i class="fa fa-archive fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>Inventory Menu 
    </h6>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h6 class="text-uppercase"><i class="fa fa-industry fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="warehouse_loc_maint_menu.html">Warehouse Location Maint Menu </a>
    </h6>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i tried by modifying the solution a little. Could achieve a solution but there is now a little space before the first character on the first line. Can you pls help.

Comment: I've updated my post a few minutes ago. If you have `&nbsp;` copied too then delete it (like in the code above now) @SalmanKazmi

Comment: Yes this space at the beginning was because of the nbsp; Thanks @Ufgu

Answer (score 0):

So you want to have a text just after the menu or indent the second menu ?

You should look this : http://jsfiddle.net/4rnNK/1/

```
ol {
    counter-reset: foo;
    display: table;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    counter-increment: foo;
    display: table-row;
}

li::before {
    content: counter(foo) ".";
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: .3em;
}
```